How can I make this div container reponsive, media query tends to show no effect on its width
I am trying to make a container that contains some commands for my bot. Everytime the screen size reduces, the container and the element messes up. Ps for some reason, width property doesnt work on it.
How it looks on normal screen
How it looks on reduced screen size
Main CSS Code
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
 .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
 .helppanel {
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-left: 25%;
      width: 70%;
    }
  .command-name {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
  }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would change margin to :0 auto ; - this will center the panel horizontally , then adjust with to 90% , this will fit better on smaller screens as well
